# F.E.A.R. 3 Sound Replacement Project - Feedback, please.

Tags: video-games, sound-design

Last week, I spent several days working on replacing the sound for the recent F.E.A.R 3 trailer featured at E3 this year. My goal is to create a compelling soundscape that draws you in and gets you excited about the game. So far, I've gotten some decent responses but very few helpful tips on how I can improve it.

I did however receive a decent suggestion to consider more clothing foley and anything else to liven up the trailer and make it breathless.  After listening to the video on a pair of great monitors, I found that I'm not quite there yet.  If you guys have any suggestions, I'd be most appreciative.

http://Hubertcampbell.Blogspot.com

[youtube]Pw2jnuDC7yw[/youtube]

Answer (score 1):

Very nice piece of design. Well done. I do agree with pretty much everything Ryan says. They are really good tips.

I would definitively make space for some of the more "real" or onscreen sounds and concentrate on them. Your atmospheric sounds are awesome but as they are throughout, they tend to drown the mix a lot. Your style works super well for many moments, but for the design to have impact, it needs to breath. **Contrast is the key!**

Even in a short trailer you have the protagonists and antagonists, and your design should make that clear. **Create conflict.** You should really try find a way to build up moments, but the build up works best if it has relative calm before and after.

Just my quick thoughts.